# Exibir alerta caso não esteja conectado com a internet

Tags: swift, xcode, webview

Como faço para exibir um alerta para o usuário caso ele não esteja conectado com a internet?

Comment: Você conseguiu solucionar o problema?

Comment: Infelizmente não.


O que realmente preciso é:


Se tem conexão exibe WebView, caso contrário carrega ImageView.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que a [solução usando somente Swift seria o código abaixo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398664/check-for-internet-connection-availability-in-swift):

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0 {
            return false
        }

        let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

        return isReachable && !needsConnection
    }

}
```

Após isso basta criar um método que vai [exibir o alerta](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/display-an-alert-view-in-ios8-with-swift), caso o método acima retorne `false`:

```
if !isConnectedToNetwork() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Conectividade", message:
        "Você não está conectado na internet!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Fechar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```